# LDAP Filter for distinguishedName EndsWith?

Tags: active-directory, ldap-query

I'm trying to build an LDAP filter which works like this simple PowerShell command:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Department -SearchBase "OU=Company Users,OU=WorkPlace,OU=contoso,DC=fr" | `
    Where{  (($_.SamAccountName -like "user1") -OR ($_.SamAccountName -like "user2") -OR ($_.SamAccountName -eq "user3")) -OR `
            ($_.Department -like "Dpt1/*") -OR `
            ($_.Department -like "Dpt2/*") -OR `
            ($_.Department -like "*/Svc3/*") -OR `
            ($_.SamAccountName -in (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Group1" -Recursive).SamAccountName)
         }
```

I tried to read some examples [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx) to make this filter but I'm stuck (error with dn):

```
(&(distinguishedName=*OU=Company Users,OU=WorkPlace,OU=contoso,DC=fr)
(!(employeeNumber=\00))(!(department=\00))
(|(department=Dpt1/*)(department=Dpt2/*)(department=*/Svc3/*)
(sAMAccountName=user1)
(sAMAccountName=user2)
(sAMAccountName=user3))
(objectCategory=person)
(sAMAccountType=805306368))
```

How can I write this filter to list users with distinguishedName values that end with `OU=Company Users,OU=WorkPlace,OU=contoso,DC=fr` or which are in this OU and subOUs?

If it helps users that I need to filter:

- need to be in the specified OU or subOUs
- need to match some samAccountNames OR Department OR Nested memberShip of a group
- need to have some attributes filled (department, employeenumber, ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Active Directory won't allow you to use wildcards for any attribute that is a distinguished name (`distinguishedName`, `member`, `manager`, etc).

If you need to find object within an OU and child OUs, then set that OU as the search base, which I see you're already doing: `-SearchBase "OU=Company Users,OU=WorkPlace,OU=contoso,DC=fr"`

Comment: Thanks @gabriel-luci . Indeed, i known how to do it in Powershell. Is there any ways to do it in a ldap query ?

Comment: LDAP is the only way to query AD. PowerShell translates that command into an LDAP query. Part of an LDAP query is the "search base" , or sometimes called "search root" or "base DN". There is always a way to set that value. What are you using to make the LDAP query?

Comment: In my case, some private old application needs to retrieve users in AD. I don't think it is possible to set some options. I prefer let them using a baseDN (wich is rootDSE) to prevent errors when someone decide to rename some OUs (in my back). To make this possible, i need to provide and LDAP filter wich do the trick ^^

Comment: There is no way to do this in the filter. The only two ways are setting the search root, or filtering the results in code after the results are returned.

Comment: @GabrielLuci - We have lots of security groups in our AD.  They often start with the first two letters *SG*.  I see lots of searches for these in our logs with an LDAP filter which looks this (&accountNameHistory=*[SG]*).  My question - is the name of a security group a DN or an attribute?

Comment: @JohnRSmith I'm not sure I understand the question, but the "name" of a security group is whatever the value of the `cn` and `name` attributes are, and is part of the `distinguishedName` (DN). The `accountNameHistory` attribute is a multi-value string, not a DN attribute, so that query is ok.

Comment: @GabrielLuci - You are a gentleman and a scholar.  Just gave a +1 on the answer.